# Jquery focus cursor after adding emoji

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to make a simple add emoji in contenteditable div. But i have a problem after added emoji cursor. I have created this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/moKJEK)** from codepen.io . In this demo you can see there is a tree example emoji. When you click first emoji the emoji will adding in the `#text` contenteditable div. So far everything is okay but after the emoji has been added, it remains behind the cursor emojis.

**After adding emoji I want you in front of the cursor emoji. How can i do that ? Anyone can help me here please ?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("paste", "#text", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("body").on("keydown", "#text", function(event) {
    //$('.character').text($(this).text().length);
    if ($(this).text().length === 200 && event.keyCode != 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  // Click to show clicked smiley
  $("body").on("click",".emoji-box", function(){
      var emojiKey = $(this).attr("data-smiley");
      var emojiURL = $(this).attr("data-url"); 
      $("#text").append("<img src="+emojiURL+" class='app-moji'>"); 
      $("#text").focus();
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-texts-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding-top:100px;
}
.input {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 0px;
}
#text {
  width:100%;
  outline:none;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#444;  
  line-height: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  text-align: left !important;
   
}
#text img { 
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
.app-moji {
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
  color:#d8dbdf;
}
.button {
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  padding:8px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#d8dbdf;
  border-raduis:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
   transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
     
}
div.coloranimation {
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  background-color:#000000;
}

.ornekgoster {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
}
.ornek {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#444;
} 

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.ap-emoji {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
   overflow:hidden;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.emoji-box {
   position:relative;
   width:29px;
   height:29px;
   float:left;  
   padding:2px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.emoji-box img {
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input">
    <div id="text" placeholder="Wite something..." contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=""/>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="ap-emoji" id="emoji1">
    <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":P" data-url="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"></div>
     <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":D" data-url="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"><img src="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"></div>
     <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley="<3" data-url="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"><img src="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you want is an **updated caret position** post insert/delete. 
You also have to take into account that user can himself update the caret position anywhere inbetween the emojis inserted.
A better solution will be to **insert HTML at a given caret position**.

This also works if you paste HTML content. Just remove your **event.preventDefault()** from your paste listener on body.

For contentEditable code you should refer solutions given by [TimDown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) on stackoverflow. His are some of the highest rated solutions. 
ContentEditable gets complex easily. I am sure your requirements won't end here.
Try using a good standard library if possible, will save you lot of time and effort.

Refer the snippet below, hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("paste", "#text", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("body").on("keydown", "#text", function(event) {
    //$('.character').text($(this).text().length);
    if ($(this).text().length === 200 && event.keyCode != 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  // Click to show clicked smiley
  $("body").on("click",".emoji-box", function(){
      var emojiKey = $(this).attr("data-smiley");
      var emojiURL = $(this).attr("data-url"); 
      //$("#text").append("<img src="+emojiURL+" class='app-moji'>"); 
      //$("#text").focus();
      insertHTMLAtCaret("<img src="+emojiURL+" class='app-moji'>")
  });
  
  function insertHTMLAtCaret(html) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);
            
            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-texts-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding-top:100px;
}
.input {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 0px;
}
#text {
  width:100%;
  outline:none;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#444;  
  line-height: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  text-align: left !important;
   
}
#text img { 
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
.app-moji {
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
  color:#d8dbdf;
}
.button {
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  padding:8px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#d8dbdf;
  border-raduis:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
   transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
     
}
div.coloranimation {
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  background-color:#000000;
}

.ornekgoster {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
}
.ornek {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#444;
} 

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.ap-emoji {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
   overflow:hidden;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.emoji-box {
   position:relative;
   width:29px;
   height:29px;
   float:left;  
   padding:2px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.emoji-box img {
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input">
    <div id="text" placeholder="Wite something..." contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=""/>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="ap-emoji" id="emoji1">
    <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":P" data-url="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"></div>
     <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":D" data-url="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"><img src="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"></div>
     <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley="<3" data-url="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"><img src="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Selection` object as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("paste", "#text", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("body").on("keydown", "#text", function(event) {
    //$('.character').text($(this).text().length);
    if ($(this).text().length === 200 && event.keyCode != 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  // Click to show clicked smiley
  $("body").on("click", ".emoji-box", function() {
    var emojiKey = $(this).attr("data-smiley");
    var emojiURL = $(this).attr("data-url");
    $("#text").append("<img src=" + emojiURL + " class='app-moji'>");
    $("#text").focus();
    var el = document.getElementById("text");
    placeCaretAtEnd(el);

  });
});

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
    typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-texts-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

#text {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left !important;
}

#text img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.app-moji {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  /* For Firefox */
  color: #d8dbdf;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d8dbdf;
  border-raduis: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

div.coloranimation {
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ornekgoster {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ornek {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ap-emoji {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.emoji-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.emoji-box img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input">
    <div id="text" placeholder="Wite something..." contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="" id="txt" />
  </div>

  <div class="ap-emoji" id="emoji1">
    <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":P" data-url="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hungry_Emoji_Icon_c20f1808-f3e2-4051-8941-3d157764e8cb.png"></div>
    <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley=":D" data-url="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"><img src="http://www.bigmouthdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Happy-Face.png"></div>
    <div class="emoji-box" data-smiley="<3" data-url="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"><img src="http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1496184263Heart-Eyes-Emoji-png-transparent-2.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is something missing in your answer. The cursor is infront of the emoji but for example: If i write this `Hi how are you ?` and after click `Hi` and if i click the emoji the emoji should be come after Hi (HERE) but it is coming after the end of text.

Answer (score 0):

## [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

For text editor functions that easily bind to buttons and target the caret position or selected area, use `execCommand()`.

#### The following demo:

- [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) and [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) interfaces are used to reference DOM elements.
- [`onclick` property event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) binds the `<form>` tag to the click event.
- The [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) properties:

  - [`event.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) returns the event ex. `"click"`, `"change"`, `"input"`, etc.
  - [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) returns the tag that was clicked, changed, text inputted in, etc.
  - [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) returns the tag that's registered to the event ex. `<form>` tag.

The callback function can insert at the caret or overwrite a selected area with a few select emoji, bold, and italicize text. The emoji unicode is in decimal format:

> `&#`**CODE**`;`

This format will render as HTML directly. For more emoji, refer to [**amp-what.com**](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/picto).

---

### Demo

```js
const edit = document.forms.editor;

const editText = event => {
  const evt = event.type;
  const tgt = event.target;
  const cur = event.currentTarget;
  const ui = cur.elements;

  if (evt === 'click') {
    switch (tgt.id) {
      case 'emoji':
        let icon = ui.picto.value;
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, icon);
        break;
      case 'bold':
        document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        break;
      case 'italic':
        document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};

edit.onclick = editText;
```

```css
button,
select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
  width: 3.25rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font: 300 2ch/1.2 'Times';
      color: #333;
    }
    
    #text {
      outline: none;
      margin: 10px;
      min-height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='editor'>
    <fieldset id="text" contenteditable="true"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id='panel'>
      <button id='bold' type='button'><b>B</b></button>
      <button id='italic' type='button'><i>I</i></button>
      <select id='picto'>
        <option value='&#11088;'>&#11088;</option>
        <option value='&#127921;'>&#127921;</option>
        <option value='&#128128;'>&#128128;</option>
        <option value='&#128163;'>&#128163;</option>
        <option value='&#129302;'>&#129302;</option>
      </select>
      <button id='emoji' type='button'>&#11088;</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    <!--JavaScript goes here-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```